# Vuejs change prop value in component after select option component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components, one creates an Editor using vue2-ace-editor, the other component is a select Option component. I Need to Change the theme of the Editor if I select another value in my select Option, so far my Editor component Looks like this:

```
<template>
    <editor v-model="content" @init="editorInit" lang="javascript" theme="monokai"></editor> <!-- the default theme is monokai currently -->
</template>

<script>


    export default {
        props: [],

        data () {
            return {
                language: 'javascript',
                content: 'test',
            }
        },

        components: {
            editor: require('vue2-ace-editor'),
        },

        methods: {
            editorInit () {
                require('brace/ext/language_tools');
                require('brace/mode/html');
                require('brace/mode/javascript');
                require('brace/mode/less');
                require('brace/theme/clouds_midnight');
                require('brace/theme/chrome');
                require('brace/theme/ambiance');
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

And my select Option Looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-select
            :items="themes"
            v-model="themeSelection"
            label="Select"
            single-line
        ></v-select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data () {
        return {
            themeSelection: null,
            themes: [
                { text: 'ambiance' },
                { text: 'chrome' },
                { text: 'clouds_midnight' },
            ]
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

So basically if I select a different Option, I Need to Change the theme of the Editor, how do I manage this?

Comment: shouldn't `theme="monokai"` be `:theme="someVariable"` ?

Comment: @Nelo_j ye but how do I manage this?

Comment: For now, the *theme* prop is static because you didn't add ":".
Your *v-select* component is switching the value of *themeSelection*. What you need is to bind your *editor*'s *theme* prop to *themeSelection*, then you can write `:theme="themeSelection"`. To share that variable between both component you may use a scoped variable, a vuex store or a parent instance.